# sync intermediate table in laravel error: Field doesn't have a default value

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I am having trouble with syncing the intermediate table in laravel 5.5.

The post blog data that came from the request is saving...but when sync the tags i get this error:

```
"SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'TagID' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `blog_post_tag` (`PostID`) values (13))"
```

Let me explain what i have:

There are 3 tables: blog_posts, blog_tags, blog_post_tag (the intermediate table)

In BlogPost model:

```
protected $table = 'blog_posts';
protected $primaryKey = 'PostID';

public function tags(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\BlogTag', 'blog_post_tag', 'PostID', 'PostID');
}
```

and BlogTag model:

```
protected $table = 'blog_tags';
protected $primaryKey = 'TagID';

// a tag can be found in multiple posts
public function posts(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\BlogPost', 'blog_post_tag', 'TagID', 'TagID');
}
```

In BLogController where i have one method that save or update the post:

The savePost method:

```
// check if update or new
// validate data
// save the post  - until here it`s ok

 // syncronize tags - here comes the problems :)
 if(isset($request->PostID) && $request->PostID != 0) {
     // update post; check if the user delete all the tags for the current post
        if(isset($request->tags)){
            // without the true - which is default - is going to remove all the id`s and put it again
            $post->tags()->sync($request->tags, true);
        }
        else
        {
            // it will remove all the associations (syncs) and is not gonna put anything!
            $post->tags()->sync(array(), true);
        }
    } else {
        // new post; use the sync method to sync the id`s in the blog_post_tag table
        $post->tags()->sync($request->tags, false);
    }
```

The $request->tags is an array with selected tags(TagsIDs):

```
<select class="form-control select2-multi" name="tags[]" multiple="multiple">
@foreach($tags as $tag)
    <option value="{{ $tag->TagID }}">{{ $tag->Name }}</option>
@endforeach
</select>
```

I don't understand what i did wrong? Why is complaining that 'TagID' doesn't have a default value. If i don't send any tags there is no error. The Error is only when update or new post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do have problems with  customization of the column names of the keys on the table.

> The third argument is the foreign key name of the model on which you
>   are defining the relationship, while the fourth argument is the
>   foreign key name of the model that you are joining to

Update your **BlogPost** model

```
protected $table = 'blog_posts';
protected $primaryKey = 'PostID';

public function tags(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\BlogTag', 'blog_post_tag', 'PostID', 'TagID');
}
```

**BlogTag** model:

```
protected $table = 'blog_tags';
protected $primaryKey = 'TagID';

// a tag can be found in multiple posts
public function posts(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\BlogPost', 'blog_post_tag', 'TagID', 'PostID');
}
```

Laravel [Doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

Let me know if you have any problems with this..